# I asked who the winner was. OR I asked who the winner had been

Tags: past-tense, reported-speech

I said, "Who was the winner". (Direct)
which would be the correct reported speech for the above direct speech? and ***WHY?***

- I asked who the winner was. OR
- I asked who the winner had been. 
  (since it is a reported speech I assume I need to use past perfect.)

Comment: They can mean different things.

Comment: @Lambie could you explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

Something happens and is finished.
Simple past.

Someone wins.
I ask**ed** who the winner **was**.
The winner was John last month.

So again, someone wins but something else happened BEFORE that.
I asked who the winner had been the year before because he wasn't this past year's winner.

the **had been** precedes he wasn't this past year's winner. He wasn't the winner this year. He had been the winner the year before.

**In general**, a simple past verb will precede a past perfect. Sometimes, though, the simple past verb is implied, not stated. Here are two simple examples of this where it is stated:

- When I arrived, he had left.

The leaving occurs BERFORE the arriving.

An image of this idea of one action preceding another:
[image]

That **timeline** image is by Robert Buckmaster.
The first arrow is the "had finished" precedes "when he arrived"

Answer (score 0):

"I asked who the winner had been" is the by-the-books correct reported speech equivalent.

But both are probably OK. "I asked who the winner **was**" is the correct reported speech equivalent for "I asked, 'Who **is** the winner?'". Since that phrase has a near-identical meaning to "I asked, 'Who was the winner?'", there's not a huge difference between the equivalent reported speech either.

All four variations sound acceptable to me. But personally, "I asked who the winner was" and "Who was the winner?" sound much more natural. My best guess is that the simple past feels less "awkward" than the past perfect.

Comment: The past perfect is not awkward when it's needed: Had the killer entered the house when lights went out?

Comment: @Lambie -- Certainly. "He said, 'I worked there'" -> "He said he had worked there". "He said he worked there" wouldn't be correct. The past perfect is needed there. "Winner" is the exception here (because once you win you don't unwin), and that's the reason "I asked who the winner was" is acceptable.

Comment: "Who is the mayor" and "Who was the mayor" have very different meanings, and in that case it's very clear that "I asked who the mayor had been" is the correct equivalent of "Who was the mayor". I think what's going on with "win" is the "is the winner/was the winner" equivalence I talked about in my answer.

Comment: Who was the mayor can become: I asked who the mayor was OR I asked who the mayor had been. Both are correct and only context will tell us which to use.